# Can't run multiple functions in a main function in Python

Tags: python, function

So a problem I'm facing is this:

I defined 2 functions and one function uses the variable of the other function
Now when I run both of them using the following code, it works properly:

```
def type_anything():
    use = input(">")
    return use


def print_it():
    print(use)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True:
        use = type_anything()
        print_it()
```

Output:

```
> abcd
abcd
> efgh
efgh
> anything
anything
```

But when I decide to make a main function that will run both the above functions and then run the main function under the "`if __name__ ==` ......" line, something like this:

```
def type_anything():
    use = input("> ")
    return use


def print_it():
    print(use)


def run_it():
    while True:
        use = type_anything()
        print_it()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    run_it()
```

The program doesn't run properly instead shows this error:

```
> anything
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/<location>/sample.py", line 17, in <module>
    run_it()
  File "C:/<location>/sample.py", line 13, in run_it
    print_it()
  File "C:/<location>/sample.py", line 7, in print_it
    print(use)
NameError: name 'use' is not defined
```

Why is this happening? What do I need to do?

Comment: One function cannot use a variable defined in another like that. That's what `return` & arguments are for. The variables need to be passed from one function to another.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a variable defined in one function in another function.

Each function needs to receive the arguments it uses.

```
def type_anything():
    use = input(">")
    return use


def print_it(use):
    print(use)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True:
        use = type_anything()
        print_it(use)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should solve your problem:

```
def type_anything():
    use = input("> ")
    return use

def print_it(use):
    print(use)

def run_it():
    while True:
        use = type_anything()
        print_it(use)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run_it()
```

The `print_it` function is not aware of any variable `use` hence the error.

Noticed how the `type_anything` function `returns` the variable `use` and the `print_it` function accepts an argument and then prints that.

Answer (score 0):

**Please do not get into the habit of using global variables, in the long run these will break everything you write. This is just an example to help you with your understanding of the problem!**

---

Your problem is variable scope. In the first example your variable `use` is `global` because you define it in the main program:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True:
        use = type_anything()
        print_it()
```

It is *not* defined in `type_anything`, you could rename this variable to whatever and it would still work:

```
def type_anything():
    x = input(">")
    return x
```

In the second example you define it in a function:

```
def run_it():
    while True:
        use = type_anything()
        print_it()
```

You *could* fix this by making `use` a global variable:

```
def run_it():
    global use
    while True:
        use = type_anything()
        print_it()
```

---

**A much better way of doing this**

---

Pass the variable `use` to the function that uses it:

```
def print_it(use):
    print(use)

def run_it():
    while True:
        use = type_anything()
        print_it(use)
```

Comment: Oh. So I was making a mistake by avoiding to pass variables to other functions. Thank you

Comment: Exactly! The problem with this is that it becomes very easy to accidentily change things you don't want and if things break it can be difficult to back track where it originally went wrong :)